# Get caret position (line number) in draft.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

How do you get the caret position in draft.js? I guess you can get the block from the selectionstate and then get the block array and see at which position the block array is, but I'm not sure this is a reliable way, or even the best way.

Comment: `blockMap` is a `OrderedMap`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can get the index of the current block like this:

```
const currentBlockKey = editorState.getSelection().getStartKey()
const currentBlockIndex = editorState.getCurrentContent().getBlockMap()
    .keySeq().findIndex(k => k === currentBlockKey)
```

Here's a fiddle with a full example: https://jsfiddle.net/cczhL821/

Comment: This work only if you want to count block ( when a user hit enter end go in second line ) but this solution did not count if text break into two lines.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the caret positon like below

```
editorState.getSelection().getFocusOffset()
```

Comment: This should be the real answer to the question get caret positon. I've updated the jsfiddle from the accepted answer to include this line