# Get top,left position of the cursor in draftjs

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

How to get the cursor position(top, left) value in Draft.js. I have already [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353569/get-caret-position-line-number-in-draft-js) this question, but it gives only the line number, but I want the top, left value.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Nope dude, I tried a lot but no avail

Comment: I compromised with just the height by getting the current caret DOM node top position in Draftjs, and substracting the DOM top position of the editor. I've changed my component that needed top + left to be full width which only needs the height.

Comment: Share the codesandbox link dude, can find a solution or it will be useful to some other dudes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for my needs (NB: not tested on multi-platform/multi-browser, but at least it works great on Chrome/Firefox on Windows). The idea is to consider the caret as a mere window selection, and not as a draftjs selection. Hope it'll help.

```
function FindCaretPosition() {
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    let selectionRange = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    selectionRange.collapse(false);
    //-----
    let caretMarker = document.createElement("span");
    caretMarker.id = "__caret";
    selectionRange.insertNode(caretMarker);
    let caretPosition = document.querySelector("#__caret").getBoundingClientRect();
    //-----
    selectionRange.deleteContents();

    return { x: caretPosition.left, y: caretPosition.bottom }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`editorState.getSelection().getAnchorOffset();`

you can get the position of cursor like that